# Scheduling a DAG in EST time zone - Airflow

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an airflow scheduler which has UTC as its time zone. I would like to schedule a DAG based on EST timings. The issue here is I want to schedule my DAG to run from 6 PM to 9 PM EST every Mon-Fri. Converting EST to UTC 6 PM becomes 10 PM and 9 PM becomes 1 AM of the next day.

I tried giving crontab expression based on UTC - **'0 10-23,1 * * MON-FRI'** but due to varying time zones my DAG will skip run of 0 AM to 1 AM (8-9 PM EST) on Fridays. Kindly help me with achieving the proper scheduling for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Change the system wide timezone.
2. Make your DAG timezone aware.

#### 1. Change the system wide timezone

In your `airflow.cfg` you can define what the scheduling timezone is.
For example for Amsterdam it would be:

```
[core]
default_timezone = Europe/Amsterdam
```

This will set the complete airflow installation to schedule based on Amsterdam times.

#### 2. Make your DAG timezone aware

If you supply a `start_date` that is timezone-aware, it will use that timezone to keep track of daylight saving time as [mentioned here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html#cron-schedules).
The following example is directly copied from [the airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html#time-zone-aware-dags)
and illustrates how to make your DAG timeozne aware.

```py
import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")

default_args=dict(
    start_date=datetime(2016, 1, 1, tzinfo=local_tz),
    owner='airflow'
)

dag = DAG('my_tz_dag', default_args=default_args)
op = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy', dag=dag)
print(dag.timezone) # <Timezone [Europe/Amsterdam]>
```

Comment: I am not allowed to change the time zone in airflow config. I will go for the second method. So by changing the start_date to EST timezone will I be able to schedule it to run on EST timings? After changing the start_date to EST timezone, the cron expression I give for scheduling will be considered as EST?

Comment: I have not tested the second option myself, but yes, exactly as you described should work.

Comment: Yes, the second method worked. Thank you and sorry for the late response.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @Rajalakshmi :) Happy that it worked for you.